# Unresolved reference: LinearLayoutManager/RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I started building a movie database app using Kotlin based on a tutorial I found online (see [this link](https://medium.com/@juanchosaravia/keddit-part-3-extension-functions-android-extensions-and-more-faa7d232f232) for details.  While building the movie fragment file, I noticed an "unresolved reference:  LinearLayoutManager" and an "unresolved reference:  RecyclerView" error. 
 I have included the code below to and everything matches up like the tutorial except for those errors:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.dburgnerjr.movietvshowdatabase.R
import com.dburgnerjr.movietvshowdatabase.commons.inflate
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.movie_fragment.*

class MovieFragment : Fragment() {

    private val movieList by lazy {
        movie_list
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return container?.inflate(R.layout.movie_fragment)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        movieList.setHasFixedSize(true)
        movieList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    }
}
```

Anything I overlooked?

Comment: Seems like the support library could be missing from your gradle dependencies, you should check/post those.

Comment: That was what it was.  Thanks.

Comment: You know the problem was in Gradle, so you should edit your question to show the original area that had the problem so the question is complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out.  I saw [this post](http://mateoj.com/2015/10/06/creating-movies-app-retrofit-picasso-android/) and noticed that I missed a

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

reference in my build.gradle file.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 10):

Considering Jetpack, you can use [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) as:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Instead of:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

And in the `layout.xml`, you need something like:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use androidx, please changed your gradle with the below.

from :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

to :

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

movieList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

use:

binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)